# How to make vertical text horizontal

Tags: python, string, input

```
shape='   _____\n  |     |\n  |     |\n  |_____|'
x=''
for i in range(2):
            x=x+shape_1
print(x)
```

I know this question has been asked a lot,but i can't find an answer for strings with shapes like this.I can't put the output because it looks weird,but it's 2 vertical rectangles.

Basically i want every time that i moves to start printing at the end of the first rectangle,so it would be 2 horizontal rectangles.

I have tried using the end function but to no avail.Is what i am trying to do possible or will the shape always get messed up.

Comment: When I print `shape`, it outputs a single box, how does the string provided above represent 2 vertical rectangles?

Comment: `x` it's equivalent to `shape*2` so yes

Comment: @Evorage        I want to do a loop where each time it will print a new box,so in this instance it would print 2 boxes,but instead of printing them vertically,I want to print them horizontally.

Comment: `' '.join([shape.split('\n')[i] for i in range(2)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to draw the left edge and the body separately.

```
left=(
'  ',
' |',
' |'
)
rest=(
'_____ ',
'     |',
'_____|',
)

def drawboxes( width, height, rows ):
    print(left[0] + rest[0] * width )
    for _ in range(height):
        for y in range(rows):
            print(left[1] + rest[1] * width )
        print(left[2] + rest[2] * width )

drawboxes(4,3,2)
```

Output:

```
  _____ _____ _____ _____
 |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |
 |_____|_____|_____|_____|
 |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |
 |_____|_____|_____|_____|
 |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |
 |_____|_____|_____|_____|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shape='   _____ \n  |     |\n  |     |\n  |_____|'
shape_arr = shape.split('\n')

x = [i for j in zip(*[shape_arr] * 2) for i in j + ('\n',)]
x = ''.join(x)
print(x)
```

The idea is to add a line after line without having '\n':

```
shape='   _____    _____ \n  |     |  |     |\n  |     |  |     |\n  |_____|  |_____|\n
```

Output

```
   _____    _____ 
  |     |  |     |
  |     |  |     |
  |_____|  |_____|
```